# In Sharepoint 2013 community, cancelling reply causing issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, community

I use SharePoint 2013!

When I try to edit the reply in the discussion list in community page,I am able to edit and save it.
Whereas, when I edit the reply and cancel it without saving it, I am not able to edit the reply again
(i.e : even if I click the edit option from the dropdown box,it does not allow me to edit. But when I refresh the page and try to edit again, it allows me to edit.)

Could anyone please try to answer my question.

Thankyou!!

Answer (score 2):

I would ask couple of question and have recommendation.

- Which browser you are using, try different browser?
- did you to use the IE with enterprise mode( compatibility mode)?
- is this behavior only with one customer or all customer?
- try to create another site collection with community template and try
  over their?
- what is SharePoint build level, may be worth to apply latest CU.

if you are getting the same behavior after all testing, then i believe you have to contact with MSFT support, may be file a bug.

Comment: This issue occurs in all browsers and for all users. Tried with new community also. Don't think last option will help :(. Will raise it to MS.